# how to debug Sencha Touch 2 apps?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How to debug Sencha touch 2?
I have been using Sencha Designer to create Sencha Touch 2 projects. I use Chrome for testing and now I want to breakpointing some of my code, how can I do that? Every time I refresh the page the break points are gone. I read something that I need to use the "?breakpoint" in the URL but I have no idea why is not working so far:

http://localhost/googlemaps/app.html?breakpoint

Also I realized the files i want to debug has a "_dc" parameter:

http://localhost/googlemaps/app/view/detalleMapa.js?_dc=1334242199729

Thanks!

Comment: Incredible that nobody knows the answer to this simple question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Chrome, you can start the "[Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/)" window from the Wrench menu > Tools > Developer tools (keyboard shortcut is "Ctrl+Shift+I").

From there, you can select the "Scripts" tab and select your script in the list of all javascript files of your page.

Once you javascript file is shown, click on the line number to add a breakpoint.

If you want to debug dynamically loaded code (see [Ext.Loader](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Loader) for details), you should add something like the following in your application:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({disableCaching: false});
```

Finally, reload your page and if the same file is loaded again, Chrome shall break the execution when executing that line.

Happy debugging!

Comment: Gaetan, thanks for your answer but it you didn't read the question where I said "Every time I refresh the page the break points are gone". It seems that you have never debugged with Sencha Touch 2

Comment: Maybe your question is : "How can I debug javascript files dynamically loaded by Sencha Touch 2" ?  Let me change the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So just an FYI... I found (search for "How to debug Sencha Touch 2 applications? - Part 1") that you can simply add "debugger;" to your script to get the Chrome debugger to break at that point.

Answer (score 0):

With chrome we get an extension for sencha, called "App Inspector for sencha, using that extension you can view the components and do the debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your phone to your PC and put this in hte browser:

chrome://inspect/#devices